# How can i run an <input type="number"> onchange event using thymeleaf?

Tags: javascript, spring, thymeleaf

Hello,

i have a little problem that maybe you could help me with. I searched the internet for quite a long time but i didn't find any answers.

I have a little web shop using Spring and Thymeleaf. My task is now to implement the option to change the quantity of a cart item inside the cart. This value is stored in a variable `${item.quantity}`.

So in conclusion if I press "up" or "down" on the input field, the item in the cart should change its quantity and the total price of all cart items should be evaluated again.

I used an `<input type="number">` combined with an onchange event running a javascript function, but all my tries went wrong.

Here is the code snippet of cart.html template:

```html
<input 
  type="number"
  onchange="change(this.value)"
  min="1"
  max="5" 
  th:value="${item.quantity}"
>
```

And this is my javascript code:

```js
<script th:inline="javascript">
/*<![CDATA[*/
function change(data) {
  var quantity = /*[[${item.quantity}]]*/ data;
  location.reload(false);
}
/*]]>*/
</script>
```

but this doesn't work.

Hopefully you understand what I mean and someone can help me, because I really don't have any idea how to else do this.

Answer (score 1):

You need to send the changed quantity back to the server. As a first step do it without JavaScript. Use a simple form, for example:

```
<form action="/change-quantity">
  <input type="hidden" name="itemId" th:value="${item.id}">
  <input type="number" min="1" max="5" th:value="${item.quantity}">
  <input type="submit" value="Update">
</form>
```

Now you need to write a POST controller for the path `/change-quantity` that looks up the item by the ID, change it's quantity and finaly redirects back to the page you came from.

Comment: You can also use `th:href="@{/{id}/change-quantity(id=${item.id})}"` if you want to use a path variable instead of the hidden field.